# Selectively silence JRuby warnings

Tags: ruby, warnings, jruby

I'm using the ruby-mysql library under JRuby and get the following warnings:

`/mysql/protocol.rb:530 warning: GC.disable does nothing on JRuby`

Is there any way to get JRuby to stop complaining about this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have a couple options.

First, you can run your program with the `-W0` option which will disable *all* warnings.  That's probably not what you want.

However, applying `-W0` is the same as setting `$VERBOSE` to `nil` -- so we can simply do that around the code where we want to suppress warnings.  This is the second and much more preferable option.

```
def suppress_all_warnings
  old_verbose = $VERBOSE
  begin
    $VERBOSE = nil
    yield if block_given?
  ensure
    # always re-set to old value, even if block raises an exception
    $VERBOSE = old_verbose
  end
end

puts "Starting"
MyConst = 1
MyConst = 2
suppress_all_warnings do
  GC.disable
end
puts "Done"
```

Running this with JRuby 1.5.0 correctly warns me about the reinitialized constant and correctly suppresses the `GC.disable` warning.

Answer (score 1):

If you switch from ruby-mysql to [activerecord-jdbcmysql-adapter](http://www.google.com/search?q=activerecord-jdbcmysql-adapter), you can avoid this warning entirely.